# How to import a custom python package in Cloud Composer?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am learning to use Google Cloud Composer and part of it is to understand how to import our organization's custom python package in the dag. I got to the point where I can import simple scripts by placing them in the dependencies folder inside the dags folder, but that's pretty much it.

I can't understand how to import the full package which contains multiple scripts and where does setup.py come into play in the import. How to structure it in the cloud storage and use it in the dag?

Comment: Can you share your sample file structure which you are trying to load it in the DAG's folder?

Comment: You might also want to check [this](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-private) documentation on how to import Python packages from private repos